# Migration from Mysql to postgre

Tags: pdo

I was working on migrating data from MYSQL to postgre.
How can I insert mysql data in postgre table?
Thanks in advance
The code:

```
try {


$conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=$direccion;dbname=$base_d", $us, $contra);

$conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


            $consulta = $conexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM ' . $tabla_b);

            //Ejecuto la consulta 
            $consulta->execute();

            $consulta_array = $consulta->fetchAll(); 


            var_export($consulta_array);

$dbconn = pg_connect("host=$direccion2 dbname=$base_d2 user=$us2 password=$contra2")
or die('No se ha podido conectar: ' . pg_last_error());

$insercion= pg_copy_from($conexion, $tabla_b2, $consulta_array,",");


        } catch (PDOException $e) {

   echo "Error conectando con la base de datos: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried working with [Pgloader](http://pgloader.io/howto/mysql.html)?

I've found it very quick and effective way to migrate MySql to Postgres.

Here is a quick example of how to proceed with Pgloader.

**Create a .load file with the below content.** (*you can exclude the unwanted lines with a "--" in front*)

```
load database  
     from      mysql://root@localhost/base_d
     into postgresql:///base_d

 WITH include drop, create tables, no truncate,  
      create indexes, reset sequences, foreign keys  

 -- SET maintenance_work_mem to '128MB', work_mem to '12MB', search_path to 'base_d'  
 CAST type datetime to timestamptz  
                drop default drop not null using zero-dates-to-null,  
      type date drop not null drop default using zero-dates-to-null  

 -- MATERIALIZE VIEWS film_list, staff_list  

 -- INCLUDING ONLY TABLE NAMES MATCHING ~/film/, 'actor'  
 -- EXCLUDING TABLE NAMES MATCHING ~<ory>  

 BEFORE LOAD DO  
 $$ create schema if not exists base_d; $$;
```

*Note that here pgloader will benefit from the meta-data information found in the MySQL database to create a PostgreSQL database capable of hosting the data as described, then load the data.*

*Note that we are using the MATERIALIZE VIEWS clause of pgloader: the selected views here will be migrated over to PostgreSQL with their contents.*

**Download Pgloader from [here](http://pgloader.io/download.html).**

**Now you can use the pgloader command to migrate data.**

$ pgloader base_d.load *(the file in which you saved the above content)*

Reference : http://pgloader.io/howto/mysql.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I tried giving out more detailed information to workout the above requirement.